# What's wrong with this php/regex query?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_replace("/(/s|^)(php|ajax|c\+\+|javascript|c#)(/s|$)/i", '$1#$2$3', $somevar);
```

It's meant to turn, for example, PHP into #PHP.

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '|'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using the forward slash (`/`) as your delimiter. When the regex engine gets to `/s` (3rd character) it thinks the regex is over and the rest of it are modifiers. But no such modifier (`|`) exists, thus the error.

Next time, you can either:

- Change your delimiters to something you won't use in your regex, ie:

  `preg_replace("!(/s|^)(php|ajax|c\+\+|javascript|c#)(/s|$)!i", '$1#$2$3', $somevar);`
- Or escape those characters with a backslash, ie: `"/something\/else/"`*

I also suspect you didn't intend to use `/s`, but the escape character `\s` that matches whitespace characters.

Comment: Thank you NullUserException. I meant to do \s... I must have just forgotten it's supposed to be around that way. This was a pretty stupid and simple mistake. Thanks.

Comment: +1: You're probably right that he intended to write \s not /s.

Answer (score 2):

The first character in the regular expression is the delimiter. If you need to use this inside your regular expression then you need to escape it:

```
"/(\/s|^)...
   ^
```

Or alternatively, choose another delimiter that isn't used anywhere in your regular expression so that you don't need to escape:

```
"~(/s|^)...(/s|$)~i"
```

I prefer to do the latter as it makes the regular expression more readable.

(Although as NullUserException points out, the actual error is that you should have used a backslash instead of a slash).